# os.walk() returning '/' instead of actual folder name

Tags: python, os.walk

I know there are a lot of questions related to this, but I can't seem to find an answer that helps me solve the problem.

I'm using os.walk() to loop through subfolders in my main folder, which contains both folders and files.

```
Main Folder
    Pass Folder
        files.txt
    Fail Folder
        files.txt
    file.txt
    file2.txt
```

So I'm using this code to create a new text file based on the subfolder names. However this returns folder/.txt, which means that dirs is returning '/' and files is returning ['file.txt', 'file2.txt'].

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dirs in root:
      new_txt = 'folder%s.txt' % (dirs)
```

How do fix it so that dirs returns ['Main Folder/Pass Folder', 'Main Folder/Fail Folder'] and files returns the files in each folder?

Comment: `root` is a string, so `for dirs in root` will iterate over it one character at a time. Is that what you want?

Comment: ohh i think my syntax is just wrong then, as I assumed that using dirs would refer back to the dirs in the os.walk().  I'm trying to make it loop through the subfolders in root.

Comment: Then you would use `for d in dirs`, rather than iterating through the string of root itself. If you only care about files and not the directories, you only need to iterate through files: `for f in files`, and to get the full path of each file use `os.path.join(root, f)`

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar to this in my code recently (which, if I recall correctly, I also found on SO). Mine went something like this:

```
    for (dirpath, subdirs, filelist) in os.walk(folder):
        # join directories in here
```

From the documentation:

> dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. dirnames is a list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..'). filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

I'm not sure os.walk() does quite what you expect. I would suggest joining the directories together using `os.path.join()` to get what you want.